# writing a video of depth images using opencv

Tags: opencv, video

I am trying to write a video with some sequence of depth map.

I have converted the depth image from cv::Mat_ to cv::Mat with single channel. 
But no codec I use is able to open the avi file I want to write. The VideoCapture.open(...) doesn't seem to be able to either create the file or open it.

I think its the problem choosing the right codec. I might be wrong. I have posted a  small code snippet.

```
cv::VideoWriter outputVideo_;
source_ = "~/Hello.avi";
cv::Size S(480, 640);
outputVideo_.open(source_, CV_FOURCC('D','I','B', ' '), 20, S, false);

if (!outputVideo_.isOpened())
{
  std::cout  << "Could not open the output video for write: " << source_ << std::endl;
  return;
}
```

How do I get opencv to work correctly in this case. I am using linux 12.04, ROS (Robot Operating System) and OpenCV 2.4.2

Comment: What is depth map data exactly? A 640x480 map of 8-bit values? Something else?

Comment: yeh the initial depth map is 640*480 float. I convert it to 640*480 8 bit which needs to be saved in the video

Comment: Maybe related to [Write 16-bit video with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9314314)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use open() function with only file name. because here with me it works well.

```
VideoWriter outputVideo_;
source_ = "~/Hello.avi";
// cv::Size S(480, 640);
outputVideo_.open(source_);

if (!outputVideo_.isOpened())
{
  std::cout  << "Could not open the output video for write: " << source_ << std::endl;
  return;
```