# saving grayscale images as video in C++

Tags: c++, opencv

In my code, there are created `cv::Mat` images whose format is `CV_16UC1`. I have a `cv::VideoWriter` object and insert created grayscale images into it. However, I have completely black video as a result. If I change the `cv::Mat` format to `CV_8UC1` everything works as expected. Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: please post your code, also why do you need `CV_16UC1` in a grayscale image?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write 16-bit video with OpenCV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314314/write-16-bit-video-with-opencv)

Comment: typical video codecs (and many image formats) don't support 16 bit format.